# Updating data type to an Object in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, types

I have changed one of the fields of my collection in mongoDB from an array of strings to an array of object containing 2 strings. New documents get inserted without any problem, but when a get method is called to get , querying all the documents I get this error:

> Failed to decode 'Students'. Decoding 'photoAddresses' errored
>   with: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is
>   DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.

photoAddresses is the field that was changed in Students.

I was wondering is there any way to update all the records so they all have the same data type, without losing any data.

The old version of photoAdresses:

```
"photoAddresses" : ["something","something else"]
```

This should be updated to the new version like this:

```
"photoAddresses" : [{photoAddresses:"something"},{photoAddresses:"something else"}]
```

Comment: And what about old documents, which have this field as a string? How do you expect them to be mapped to an object? You need to update your old documents.

Comment: That's exactly it! I need them to get updated to be like the new ones (each string in the array would be an object with one of the strings as null), but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "each string in the array would be an object"? Could you post your current and old photoAddresses object?

Comment: @SagarAhuja I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: I posted an answer. Please let me know if it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregation queries update the string array to object array, only if the array has string elements. The aggregation operator [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) is used to map the *string* array elements to *objects*. You can use any of the two queries.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { $and: [ { $isArray: "$photo" }, 
                           { $gt: [ { $size: "$photo" }, 0 ] }
                         ] 
          }, 
          "photo.0": { $type: "string" }
      } 
  },
  {
      $project: {
          photo: { 
              $map: {
                   input: "$photo", 
                      as: "ph", 
                      in: { addr: "$$ph" } 
               } 
          }
      } 
  },
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { photo: doc.photo } } ) )
```

The following query works with MongoDB version 4.2+ only. Note the update operation is an *aggregation* instead of an *update*. See [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html).

```
db.test.updateMany(
  { 
          $expr: { $and: [ { $isArray: "$photo" }, 
                           { $gt: [ { $size: "$photo" }, 0 ] }
                         ] 
          }, 
          "photo.0": { $type: "string" }
  },
  [
    {
      $set: {
          photo: { 
              $map: {
                   input: "$photo", 
                      as: "ph", 
                      in: { addr: "$$ph" } 
               } 
          }
      } 
    }
  ]
)
```

---

[**EDIT ADD**]: The following query works with version **MongoDB 3.4**:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          matches: {
              $cond: {
                  if: { $and: [ 
                          { $isArray: "$photoAddresses" }, 
                          { $gt: [ { $size: "$photoAddresses" }, 0 ] },
                          { $eq: [ { $type: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$photoAddresses", 0 ] } }, "string" ] }
                       ] },
                  then: true,
                  else: false
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $match: { matches: true }
  },
  {
      $project: {
          photoAddresses: { 
              $map:  {
                   input: "$photoAddresses", 
                      as: "ph", 
                      in: { photoAddresses: "$$ph" } 
               } 
          }
      } 
  },
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { photoAddresses: doc.photoAddresses } } ) )
```

Comment: The first query does not seem to work! I don't think I quite understand it though, what does the project part do?

Comment: _The first query does not seem to work!_ Please tell what is it you think is not working. I know it works. It converts the string array `"photo" : [ "photo-1", "photo-2" ]` to an array of objects: `{ "_id" : 1, "photo" : [ { "addr" : "photo-1" }, { "addr" : "photo-2" } ] }`.

Comment: _I don't think I quite understand it though, what does the project part do?_ The `$project` used with `$map` converts (maps) the array of strings to array objects.

Comment: Do you have a solution for version 3.4! I ran the query on my local and it worked perfectly. But my server has this version of mongo and I can't upgrade it right now.

Comment: I get this error for both queries: ""errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr"
"

Comment: Which of the queries are you using - the first one?

Comment: Okay. I added query code for **MongoDB version 3.4** to the answer.