# How to update a field array of strings to array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to update document's `array of string` to `array of object` using MongoShell Command?

```
people
[
   { 
      name: 'John',
      friends: ['Mary', 'Jane', 'Steve']
   },
   { 
      name: 'Michael',
      friends: ['John']
   },
...
]
```

to

```
people
[
   { 
        name: 'John',
        friends: [{ name: 'Mary' }, {name: 'Jane'}, {name: 'Steve'}]
   },
   { 
        name: 'Michael',
        friends: [{name: 'John'}]
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Here is a similar question and an answer: [Updating data type to an Object in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467973/updating-data-type-to-an-object-in-mongodb). The solution uses the `$map` aggregation array operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating data type to an Object in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467973/updating-data-type-to-an-object-in-mongodb) Marking this question as dup..