# MongoDB 4.0.12 update nested array with concat

Tags: mongodb

Mongo DB 4.0

I want to update all elements of an array of an document by concatenate fields
I have following document:

```
{
  "id": 123455,
  "articles": [
    {
      "country": "DE",
      "articleNumber": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "country": "AT",
      "articleNumber": "987654321"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need extends article with a new field which is concatenate by to other fields

```
{
  "id": 123455,
  "articles": [
    {
      "country": "DE",
      "articleNumber": "123456789",
      "countryArticleNumber": "DE123456789"
    },
    {
      "country": "AT",
      "articleNumber": "987654321",
      "countryArticleNumber": "AT987654321"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried several solutions I found here in Stackoverflow like:

```
db.articleDocument.update (
  {_id: ObjectId('5f15414ff3812f4838391edd')},
  {
    $push:
      {'articles.countryArticleNumber': 'dasd'}
  }
  )
```

but even with a simple update I got

> MongoWriteException: Cannot create field 'countryArticleNumber' in
> element {articles: [ {

I also tried with db.articleDocument.updateOne,  $set instead of $push, positional operator

I was expecting something like this should work

```
db.articleDocument.updateOne(
  {_id: ObjectId('5f15414ff3812f4838391edd')},
  {
    $set:
      {
        "articles.$.countryArticleNumber": {
          $concat: ["articles.$.country", "articles.$.articleNumber"]
        }
      }
  }
  )
```

but

> The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.

Thx in advanced

Comment: You need to use [Update with Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html). The aggregation uses the [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) array operator.

Comment: @prasad_ you are referring to version 4.4 documentation. 
Unfortunately I am using MongoDB 4.0.

Comment: I meant, MongoDB v4.2 (the Aggregation Update is available from v4.2 onwards). You can still use the _same_ aggregation pipeline and then an update - it will be a two step operation.

Comment: There is now also `$addToSet`, (also 4.2 I believe) which CAN be used with update, and it will create the array if it's missing. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: Here is a similar post with an answer: [Updating data type to an Object in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467973/updating-data-type-to-an-object-in-mongodb). Note the `$map` usage, where you can create the `countryArticleNumber`, using the two existing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **v4.0**, might be one solution you have to perform two queries,

- use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/aggregation/) with `$map` and `$project` or `$addFields`
- update returned aggregation result using `updateOne()`

```
db.articleDocument.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("5f15414ff3812f4838391edd")
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      articles: {
        $map: {
          input: "$articles",
          as: "article",
          in: {
            country: "$$article.country",
            articleNumber: "$$article.articleNumber",
            countryArticleNumber: {
              $concat: [
                "$$article.country",
                "$$article.articleNumber"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
.forEach(function(doc) { 
  db.articleDocument.updateOne( 
    { _id: doc._id }, 
    { $set: { articles: doc.articles } } 
  )
})
```

Alternatively can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) instead of `$project`,

Aggregation [Working Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p6RAe4gcU_M)

---

For **v4.2**, There are new feature [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/),

```
db.articleDocument.updateMany(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f15414ff3812f4838391edd")
    },
    [
        {
            $addFields: {
                articles: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$articles",
                        as: "article",
                        in: {
                            country: "$$article.country",
                            articleNumber: "$$article.articleNumber",
                            countryArticleNumber: {
                                $concat: [
                                    "$$article.country",
                                    "$$article.articleNumber"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

> **Note:** Make sure mongo shell version should be >= 4.2

Comment: I tried the aggregate function you provided to see the result but i got:
"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'"

Worked in MongoPlayground but not on Mongo 4.0

Comment: Thx - now Aggregrate works. 
But i got a SyntaxError in for each at doc => 
any idea?

Comment: I am executing this in IntelliJ Database Tab

Comment: thx - aggregation is working fine but the iteration does not work. 
java.lang.Exception: TypeError: Right-hand-side of instanceof is not an object TypeError: Right-hand-side of instanceof is not an object at Iterator.Iterator (all-standalone.js:79096:25)

maybe this has something to do with Intellj

Comment: can you try `.forEach(function(doc){ db.articleDocument.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { articles: doc.articles } } )})`

Comment: yes the same error above
java.lang.Exception: TypeError: Right-hand-side of instanceof is not an object TypeError: Right-hand-side of instanceof is not an object at Iterator.Iterator (all-standalone.js:79096:25) at default (all-standalone.js:79148:12) at user_script:1 ...

Comment: I also tried to execute this in mongosh 
"Calling custom forEach method may not work as expected because callback is async. Try converting to array type before calling forEach."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218980/discussion-between-turivishal-and-dco).

Comment: We are going to update our MongoDB to 4.2 - Ill try again and keep you updated

Comment: Good, i have updated an answer with solution for 4.2 version.